# How to select a random row?

Tags: sql, sqlite, random

How can I get a random record from a table in SQLite? This is for "Word of the day" to get a random record from database for today, a different random record tomorrow.

`ORDER BY RAND(20120714) LIMIT 1` works in MySQL, but how to do this in SQLite?

Comment: Come on, this is a 5 second search on google

Comment: if you have auto incremented ID, then don't you just need to get the count of records, make a random number (nextInt(count)+1) based on the count of records, then select the record based on that randomized ID and you're done?

Comment: Problem is I don't have autoincremented IDs, and IDs are not integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not allow to seed its random number generator.

You have to compute the random number in your own code.
This is easy only if the records have consecutive numbers, i.e., autoincrementing IDs; you should change your database.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```sql
select * from table limit 1 offset (select julianday()%<num_of_rows> from table);
```

You can calculate `num_of_rows` easily with the query (you can even embed it as a sub query in the query above):

```sql
select count(*) from table;
```

#### Explanation

`julianday()` is a SQLite [function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) that returns the [Julian Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) of today.
To get the row in the table, all you need to do is to calculate the offset: `julian_day % rows_in_table`.